# Generate mesh and refine mesh of triangles

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, physics-engine

I need to find a way to mesh triangles then to refine using refine.
My vertices of my original triangles are stored inside a matrix of size nb_points * 2.
My faces are stored in a nb_faces * 3 matrix.
The data for each face is stored in a nb_face * 1 matrix.
The meshing is done by diving the area using the middles of the segments of the triangles.

Example :
Origin :

```
vertices = [0 1 ; 
            2 3 ; 
            4 1 ;
            4 5];
faces = [1 2 3;
         2 3 4];
data = [1 2];
```

[image: Picture of the figure]

Result expected after meshing :

```
vertices = [0 1; 
            2 3; 
            4 1;
            4 5;
            1 2;
            3 2;
            2 1;
            3 4;
            4 3];
faces = [1 5 7;
         2 5 6;
         5 6 7;
         7 6 3;
         2 6 8;
         6 8 9;
         6 9 3;
         8 4 9];
data = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2];
```

[image: Picture of the new figure]

I am displaying using :

```
FV.Vertices = vertices; 
FV.Faces = faces; 
FV.FaceVertexCData = data;
figure; hold on; axis equal; grid on;
patch(FV,'FaceColor','flat');
```

Precision :
I do not want to use the following functions which gives way too many vertices and faces :

- [`generateMesh()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pde.pdemodel.generatemesh.html)
- [`refinemesh()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pde.pdemodel.generatemesh.html)

The data are temperatures since this is a simulation of heat transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a for loop it can be done quite easily, here is one solution:

```
% Dummy data
vertices = [0 1 ; 
            2 3 ; 
            4 1 ;
            4 5];
faces = [1 2 3;
         2 3 4];
data = [1 2]; 

% Number of vertices
vnum = size(vertices,1);

% new faces empty vector
nfaces = [];

% triangular shift
tshift = [2,-1,-1].';

% Run the algorithm
for ii = 1:size(faces,1)
    % For each triangle get the 3 pairs of vertices
    nsk = [faces(ii,1), faces(ii,2);faces(ii,2), faces(ii,3);faces(ii,3), faces(ii,1)];
    % Compute the center of each pair of vertices
    cmiddle = (vertices(nsk(:,1),:)+vertices(nsk(:,2),:))/2
    % Compute the new faces
    nfaces = [nfaces;[nsk(:,1),vnum+(ii*3-3+[1:3].'),vnum+(ii*3-3+[1:3].')+tshift];[(vnum+(ii*3-2)):(vnum+(ii*3))]]
    % Add the new vertices
    vertices = [vertices;cmiddle];
end

% Delete the duplicate vertices
[vertices,~,ind] = unique(vertices,'rows');
faces = ind(nfaces);

% Plot
figure; hold on; axis equal; grid on;
patch('Faces',faces,'Vertices',vertices,'FaceVertexCData',kron(data,ones(1,4)).','FaceColor','flat')
colorbar
```

If you find a way to generate the `nsk` vector without for loop you could even get rid of the loop. This code will only work on triangle, but it can be adapted if needed.

Result:

[image]

You can repeat the operation:

[image]