# Remeshing of a triangular mesh for making high quality Delaunay triangulation?

Tags: matlab, mesh, triangulation, delaunay, geometry-surface

I have a triangular mesh of the brain surface. I want to remesh it to a high-quality Delaunay triangulation. I'm seeking an easy and straightforward method.

Comment: Is that a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59382625/generate-mesh-and-refine-mesh-of-triangles/59396850#59396850) ?

Comment: @obchardon No, this is a different issue. This one is about remeshing, not refining a mesh.

Answer (score 1):

[pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh#surface-remeshing) interfaces CGAL and has surface remeshing. Install CGAL, then install pygalmesh with

```
pip install pygalmesh
```

Then you can use

```
pygalmesh-remesh-surface lion-head.off out.vtu -e 0.025 -a 25 -s 0.1 -d 0.001
```

on the command line.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @nico Schlomer , Can I use of pygalmesh on Windows?

Comment: Sure. You'll have to install cgal first though.

Comment: Hi @Nico Schlomer, I installed _CGAL, Eigen, pygalmesh_ then used your example, but it does not work! I get the following error : pygalmesh-remesh-surface is not recognize as an internal or external command... ! may you help me in this problem? thanks alot.

Comment: @Fatemeh This comment section is the wrong place for installation support.

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: @Fatemeh GitHub issues https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh/issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if C++ is an option for you but the [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org) library provides such a functionality. See [this package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/), see in particular [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/#title24).

If you want to use a GUI, you can use the CGAL polyhedron demo. You can compile it yourself by compiling the code in `demo/Polyhedron` from a release or use the pre-compiled windows demo available: [demo](https://www.cgal.org/demo/5.0.1/polyhedron_3.zip) + [dlls](https://www.cgal.org/demo/5.0.1/CGAL-demoDLLs.zip) to be extracted in the directory of the demo. Load your input mesh, select it and click on Operations -> Tetrahedral Mesh Generation -> Create a Surface Triangle Mesh

Comment: Thank you @sloriot . About your first offer, how can I convert FEM (a .txt file) to .OFF file ?

Comment: I'm beginner with CGAL, I tried run a axample, but I got the following error :Severity Code Description Project File Line Source Suppression State
Error C4996 'CGAL::Diagonalize_traits<FT,3>::diagonalize_selfadjoint_covariance_matrix': CGAL::Diagonalize_traits is a deprecated class that can lead to precision issues, please use CGAL::Eigen_diagonalize_traits TryCGAL c:\dev\cgal-4.14\include\cgal\default_diagonalize_traits.h 74 Build

Comment: This is just a warning that disappear if you have Eigen installed and configured at the cmake step. Alternatively the warning can be disactivated by defining `CGAL_I_WANT_TO_USE_DIAGONALIZE_TRAITS`.

Comment: Dear @sloriot, unfortunately, I couldn't execute an example in CGAL, Also I am not familiar with your second offer about using CGAL polyhedron demo!! may explain more, please?!

Comment: @slroriot, I executed the example which you have linked for remeshing in CGAL, but it doesn't make a Delaunay triangulation !! may you help me whether I should write a program or there is a ready example for this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want to resample the mesh? I've had some success using the trimesh package: https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh

Check out `trimesh.remesh` in particular.

Comment: thanks @Jussi , I need a high-quality mesh! Does trimesh do that?

Comment: How do you define "high quality"? The remeshing/resampling algorithms are probably quite similar between libraries. Usually you can set the desired mesh density using e.g. target vertex distance, and then the algorithm will interpolate between existing vertices.

Comment: I mean that I want to convert the triangulation mesh to one that is Delaunay triangulation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JIGSAW`](https://github.com/dengwirda/jigsaw-matlab) for surface (re)meshing. Similarly to `CGAL`, it offers various Delaunay-based methods to discretise planar/surface/volume domains, with a focus on high quality mesh creation.

Though `JIGSAW` itself is a `c++` code, you can run it directly from either `MATLAB` or `Python`. To install, you'll need a `c++` compiler and `cmake`. Click through to `GitHub` for additional instructions and examples.

---

**I'm a developer of `JIGSAW`, so keep this in mind I guess! Otherwise, in addition to `CGAL`, the [`MMG`](https://github.com/MmgTools/mmg) or [`Geogram`](http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html) packages may also be of interest.

Comment: Dear @Darren Engwirda, I want to use _JIGSAW_ for remeshing, I get _'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file._ in MATLAB, while I installed _cmake_ and _c++ compiler_ at first. may do you help me, please?

Comment: @Fatemeh It seems that `MATLAB` is unable to find your `cmake` installation. I'm happy to try to help here, but this is more of an `OS` issue than anything to do with `JIGSAW` directly. This thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31675150/cmake-command-is-not-recognized?rq=1) suggests adding `cmake` to your `path` variable (if you're using `Windows`...)